# Inkscape tiled clones based on px

Tags: inkscape, tiles

I need to have 15 clones of an object 50 px apart. But I am only able to use 170 % distance through the X-axis. Whenever I try to use 50 px as width and 0 px as height, no clones are created. Please check the image below

[image]

The first row, I am doing it manually because I don't know the exact X-axis distance in %. It would be great if someone with knowledge of Inkscape can tell me how to make 15 of them in a row with 50 px spacing. Tiled clones or some other method. Thanks.

This is what I have now

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way would be to make the original hold an additional transparent rectangle. If you group it with the arrow, you can later delete it, after tiling.

Another way would be to calculate the correct distance (percentage of object width), and then to put that into the field - so if your arrow is, say, 50px wide, write 100% into the field to get an additional 50px.

Yet another way would be to search for the feature request in Inkscape's bug tracker and to upvote it, or to create the request if it does not exist yet (I think it does, but maybe in the old launchpad tracker, see http://alpha.inkscape.org/bug-migration/). And then to wait, or to find someone to implement the feature.

Comment: The rectangle method worked. If I may, how can we calculate percentage of object width ? Thanks.